# Mongoose Schema calling Itself is not getting _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am trying to create a mongoose schema that is an item.  That item might have sub items underneath.  Example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    description: { en_US: String },
    title: { en_US: String },
    subtitle: { en_US: String },
    type: String,
    value: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    items: [{type: Schema.Types.Object, ref: 'ItemSchema'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

When I call the code the and pass the item object json that looks like this:

```
"items": [{
            "type": "photo",
            "title": {
                "en_US": "Add Photo"
            }
        },
        {
            "required": true,
            "type": "list",
            "title": {
                "en_US": "Select Type of Call"
            },
            "items": [{
                    "type": "list_option",
                    "title": {
                        "en_US": "Homework Help"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "list_option",
                    "title": {
                        "en_US": "Not Available"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
```

The photo and list Items get an _id but not the others... Here is the result:

```
 "items": [
        {
            "type": "photo",
            "_id": "5a1d99f5ceec230014b83d81",
            "items": [],
            "title": {
                "en_US": "Add Photo"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "list",
            "_id": "5a1d99f5ceec230014b83d80",
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": {
                        "en_US": "Homework Help"
                    },
                    "type": "list_option"
                },
                {
                    "title": {
                        "en_US": "Not Available"
                    },
                    "type": "list_option"
                }
            ]
         }]
```

I will never know how many sub-items there will be or it can go as far as 10 levels deep of sub-items (ex. car-ford-compact-escort (each a different sub level)).  How can I get the items to create _ids for all the sub-items it has?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a way around this.  So first off the data was coming to the function as a single object with multiple items inside it.  What I had to do was write a function that created the looping action with a mongoose schema that included _id.  Here is how the mongoose schema looked:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    description: { en_US: String },
    title: { en_US: String },
    type: String,
    value: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    items: [{type: Schema.Types.Object, ref: 'ItemSchema'}]
});
```

Now when I saved the data I could not just save the whole items object at once.  Instead I need to walk though the items and save each one separate like this:

```
function nextItem(item){
    var saveItem = Item({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        description: item.description,
        title: item.title,
        type: item.type,
        value: item.value
    });

    var fullItem = saveItem;

    if(item.items){
        fullItem.items = [];
        item.items.forEach(function(item){
             var tempItem = newItem(item);
             fullItem.items.push(tempItem);
        });
        return fullItem
    } else {
        return fullItem
    }
}
```

this would create the correct Items object and with _ids that were unique so I could search for them later.  It even allowed me to do the same thing to items arrays inside other objects and save the parent object with the correct item _ids.  I hope this can help someone else also.